# Docker worker node promote failing

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

**Steps to reproduce the issue:**

1. I am creating 5 node docker cluster AWS instances
2. Terminate the leader(Primary Manager) from AWS console
3. docker node demote (primary-node) from the terminal
4. docker node rm (primary-node)
5. docker node promote (worker-node) / docker node update (worker-node) --role manager

After Step 5 , 
Status of the worker node is **down** 
Availability is **active**.

**Status of the worker node is always down**

I tried

```
docker node update  --availability active (worker-node)
```

But it doesnt help

**Output of `docker version`:**
`Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40`

**Output of `docker info`:**

```
Containers: 5
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 5
Images: 18
Server Version: 18.03.1-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: active
 NodeID: pw2cgzi62tr1g5yn42gdue9sd
 Is Manager: true
 ClusterID: 4l9ngpfnlqov063np7efi9idw
 Managers: 2
 Nodes: 4
 Orchestration:
  Task History Retention Limit: 5
 Raft:
  Snapshot Interval: 10000
  Number of Old Snapshots to Retain: 0
  Heartbeat Tick: 1
  Election Tick: 10
 Dispatcher:
  Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
 CA Configuration:
  Expiry Duration: 3 months
  Force Rotate: 0
 Autolock Managers: false
 Root Rotation In Progress: false
 Node Address: 172.31.4.129
 Manager Addresses:
  172.31.4.129:2377
  172.31.6.143:2377
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 773c489c9c1b21a6d78b5c538cd395416ec50f88
runc version: 4fc53a81fb7c994640722ac585fa9ca548971871
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-1060-aws
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 990.7MiB
Name: ip-172-31-4-129
ID: CBXR:P6YF:ICCQ:R7LT:XM4M:BBMD:N4FN:ZPRI:3VOC:FO54:Y7I6:6LHK
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix is as below:

1) When the primary leader leaves the cluster, swarm will chose a new leader.

2) Generate manager token of the New Primary leader

3) SSH into worker . Docker swarm leave  . Docker swarm join with manager token